# Submit button not validate form - Parsley js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, parsley

As the title says, the submission button is not a valid form, while when I write on the form yes, it is as if it does not activate the validation of the form and I don't understand why.

Here is the code ...

```
<form class="w-full h-auto flex flex-col justify-center items-center py-5 px-10 mx-12 bg-white radius" id="registrati" >

        <p class="text-6xl lg:text-xl text-black bold mb-5">Registrati</p>

        <div class="flex justify-center items-center w-full mb-5 lg:mb-2 relative">
          <i class="fas fa-user w-1/12"></i>
          <input class="transparence-input w-3/4 radius p-1 px-10" type="text" name="nome" value="" placeholder="Nome" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="focus keyup submit" data-parsley-required-message="Campo obbligatorio">
          <div class="error-field-icon flex hidden">
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle text-red-800"></i>
            <p class="div-error px-1 absolute text-white lg:text-sm radius h-auto hidden"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="div-check hidden">
            <i class="fas fa-check text-green-500 "></i>
          </div>
        </div>



        <input class="radius p-1 px-10 bg-black text-giallo mt-2" type="button" name="submit" value="Registrati!">

      </form>
```

And this is the javascript code:

```
$('form#registrati').parsley().on('form:success', function(){

  //Code after success validate form

})
.on('form:submit', function(){
  return false;
})
.on('field:error', function(){
  //....
})
.on('field:success', function(){ 
  //...
})
```

Comment: what are you trying to do and what is not working ?

Comment: When I click on submit without having filled in all the fields of the form, the form should validate and resist the errors of the various fields, instead this behavior is only there when I actually write on the text field

Comment: I also tried to trigger, 'submit', but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Ok I found it registered